# I am learning spring-security I am getting Unsatisfied Dependency Exception I don't understand what is wrong

Tags: spring, spring-boot, spring-mvc, spring-security, spring-oauth2

error:

```
org.springframework.beans.factory.UnsatisfiedDependencyException: Error creating bean with name 'org.springframework.security.config.annotation.web.configuration.WebSecurityConfiguration': Unsatisfied dependency expressed through method 'setFilterChains' parameter 0; nested exception is org.springframework.beans.factory.BeanCreationException: Error creating bean with name 'securityFilterChain' defined in class path resource [com/himanshu/spring/security/config/WebSecurityConfig.class]: Bean instantiation via factory method failed; nested exception is org.springframework.beans.BeanInstantiationException: Failed to instantiate [org.springframework.security.web.SecurityFilterChain]: Factory method 'securityFilterChain' threw exception; nested exception is org.springframework.beans.factory.BeanCreationException: Error creating bean with name 'clientRegistrationRepository' defined in class path resource
```

WebSecurityconfig.java file :

```
package com.himanshu.spring.security.config;

import org.springframework.context.annotation.Bean;
import org.springframework.context.annotation.Configuration;
import org.springframework.security.config.Customizer;
import org.springframework.security.config.annotation.web.builders.HttpSecurity;
import org.springframework.security.config.annotation.web.configuration.EnableWebSecurity;
import org.springframework.security.crypto.bcrypt.BCryptPasswordEncoder;
import org.springframework.security.crypto.password.PasswordEncoder;
import org.springframework.security.web.SecurityFilterChain;
import org.springframework.stereotype.Component;

@EnableWebSecurity
@Configuration
public class WebSecurityConfig {

    private static final String[] WHITE_LISTS = {
            "/hello*",
            "/register*",
            "/verifyRegistration*",
            "/resendVerificationToken*"
    };

    @Bean
    public PasswordEncoder passwordEncoder(){
        return new BCryptPasswordEncoder(11);
    };

    @Bean
    SecurityFilterChain securityFilterChain(HttpSecurity http) throws Exception{
        http.
                cors()
                .and()
                .csrf()
                .disable()
                .authorizeHttpRequests()
                .antMatchers(WHITE_LISTS).permitAll()
                .antMatchers("/api/**").authenticated()
                .and()
                .oauth2Login(oauth2Login ->
                        oauth2Login.loginPage("/oauth2/authorization/api-client-oidc"))
                .oauth2Client(Customizer.withDefaults());

        return http.build();
    }
}
```

I think the error in this file file but I don't understand what to do. My authorization-server is working all fine their is no exception while running the application but I think their are some error in spring-security client. I have also provided **application.yaml** here.

This is my application.yaml file:

```
spring:
  datasource:
    url: jdbc:mysql://localhost:3306/usr_reg
    username: root
    password: Hima@63546
    driver-class-name: com.mysql.cj.jdbc.Driver

  jpa:
    show-sql: true
    hibernate:
      ddl-auto: update

  security:
    oauth2:
      client:
        registration:
          api-client-oidc:
            provider: spring
            client-id: api-client
            client-secret: secret
            authorization-grant-type: authorization_code
            redirect-uri: "http://127.0.0.1:8080/login/oauth2/code/{registrationId}"
            scope: openid
            client-name: api-client-oidc
          api-client-authorization-code:
            provider: spring
            client-id: api-client
            client-secret: secret
            authorization-grant-type: authorization_code
            redirect-uri: "http://127.0.0.1:8080/authorized"
            scope: api.read
            client-name: api-client-authorization-code
        provider:
          spring:
            issuer-url: http://auth-server:9090
```

Comment: The problem is "Error creating bean with name 'clientRegistrationRepository' defined in class path resource". Please check the logs for issues and how does the clientRegistrationRepository look like?

Comment: Is there anything more to the error on subsequent lines of the log? Caused by?

Comment: Yes, there are many log lines..

Comment: It maybe ordering issue. Try to put `.and().authorizeHttpRequests()` after `permitAll()` and befre `antMatchers().authenticated()`

Comment: Thanks dude but it is not possible..